# solve nonlinear equations with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, nonlinear

I am trying to solve a set of equations with NDSolve. one of them is `mg*yg''[t] == NN[t] - kb*yg[t]^1 - cb*yg'[t],` 
When the power of yg[t] is 1 the equations could be solved but when I change the power of the yg[t] from 1 to 1.0001 and introduce nonlinearity I get this error.

> The function is not a real number when the arguments are {1.1187*10^-6,0.000156175 +0. i,139.599 +0. i,0.000156184 +0. i,139.612 +0. i,0.000390461 +0. i,349.034 +0. i,0.000390459 +0. i,349.031 +0. i,-4.58818*10^-16+0. i,-1.55506*10^-9+8.73722*10^-18 i,2.83753*10^-15+0. i,9.61059*10^-9+0. i,-1}.

as you can see the imaginary parts are so small (for example 2.83753*10^-15), actually it seems a numerical error. I there any way to ask NDSolve neglects the imaginary parts when they are so small?

```
aa = Array[n, {51, 1}];
aa[[1 ;; 31, 1]] = 3*10^8;
aa[[32 ;; 51, 1]] = 1*10^8;


k = 400;
KT = Array[n, {51*k, 1}];
For[ii = 1, ii <= k, ii = ii + 1,
  KT[[51*(ii - 1) + 1 ;; 51*(ii)]] = aa[[1 ;; 51, 1]]
  ];
km[t_] = Interpolation[
   KT, ((Subscript[\[Theta], p][t] 180)/(0.2 Pi) + 1)];

N1 = 36; N2 = 90; MM = 1.5; a = 20 Degree;

rp = (N1*MM)/2000*Cos[a];
rg = (N2*MM)/2000*Cos[a];
Ip = 1/2 mp (rp/Cos[a

])^2;
Ig = 1/2 mg (rg/Cos[a])^2;
Imm = 0.021;
Ib = 0.0105;


mp = 0.289;
mg = 1.789;
Tin = 50;
Tout = 125;

kb = 6*10^8;
cb = 1.8*10^3;
kt = 10^4;
ct = 10;

cm[t_] := If[km[t] >= 2*10^8, 1147, 869];

NN[t_] := 
  km[t] (yp[t] - yg[t] - rp Subscript[\[Theta], p][t] + 
      rg Subscript[\[Theta], g][t]) + 
   cm[t] (yp'[t] - yg'[t] - rp Subscript[\[Theta], p]'[t] + 
      rg Subscript[\[Theta], g]'[t]);

T = .01; omega = 2 Pi 55.55;
sol = {yp[t], yg[t], Subscript[\[Theta], p]'[t], 
    Subscript[\[Theta], g]'[t], Subscript[\[Theta], p][t], 
    Subscript[\[Theta], g][t]} /. NDSolve[{

     mp*yp''[t] == -NN[t] - kb*yp[t] - cb*yp'[t],

     mg*yg''[t] == NN[t] - kb*yg[t]^1.0001 - cb*yg'[t],

     Imm*Subscript[\[Theta], m]''[
        t] == -kt (Subscript[\[Theta], m][t] - 
          Subscript[\[Theta], p][t]) - 
       ct (Subscript[\[Theta], m]'[t] - Subscript[\[Theta], p]'[t]) + 
       Tin,

     Ib*Subscript[\[Theta], b]''[
        t] == -kt (Subscript[\[Theta], b][t] - 
          Subscript[\[Theta], g][t]) - 
       ct (Subscript[\[Theta], b]'[t] - Subscript[\[Theta], g]'[t]) - 
       Tout,


     Ip*Subscript[\[Theta], p]''[t] == 
      rp NN[t] - 
       kt (Subscript[\[Theta], p][t] - Subscript[\[Theta], m][t]) - 
       ct (Subscript[\[Theta], p]'[t] - Subscript[\[Theta], m]'[t]),

     Ig*Subscript[\[Theta], g]''[t] == -rg NN[t] - 
       kt (Subscript[\[Theta], g][t] - Subscript[\[Theta], b][t]) - 
       ct (Subscript[\[Theta], g]'[t] - Subscript[\[Theta], b]'[t]),


     yp[0] == 0, yg[0] == 0, yp'[0] == 0, yg'[0] == 0, 
     Subscript[\[Theta], m][0] == 0, Subscript[\[Theta], p][0] == 0, 
     Subscript[\[Theta], b][0] == 0, Subscript[\[Theta], g][0] == 0, 
     Subscript[\[Theta], m]'[0] == omega, 
     Subscript[\[Theta], p]'[0] == omega, 
     Subscript[\[Theta], b]'[0] == omega*N1/N2, 
     Subscript[\[Theta], g]'[0] == omega*N1/N2},
    {yp, yg, Subscript[\[Theta], m], Subscript[\[Theta], b], 
     Subscript[\[Theta], g], Subscript[\[Theta], p]},
    {t, 0, T}];
```

Comment: How do you call `NDSolve`? What range of `t` do you want?

Comment: Is `yg[t]` negative?  If so, taking a non-integer power of it will generally yield a complex number.  If you're trying to do some kind of damped oscillator with non-linear friction, you probably want `Abs[yg[t]]^n` instead.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert As I mentioned I think it is a numerical error when t is near zero.

Comment: @Ali  To obtain really useful answers, please include a complete set of commands that actually can be run by the reader.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you, I added the code.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert
You were absolutely right about the negative yg[t].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors occur because `yg[t]^1.0001` is complex, causing all six dependent variable to become complex.  But, the `Interpolation` function in `km` only has data to allow it to compute real values.  Hence, the error.  You ask whether the small  imaginary part of `yg[t]^1.0001` can be ignored. Certainly, it can from a mathematical perspective.  Simply use `Re[yg[t]^1.0001]` instead.  Results for `yp` and `yg` are

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[sol[[1, i]], {i, 2}] /. t -> t0], {t0, 0, T}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "yp, yg"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]]
```

[image]

`yg` is negative except at very small `t`.  I recommend that you consider ways to eliminate `Interpolation`, which would allow you to proceed without assuming `Im[yg[t]^1.0001]` can be ignored.

Comment: Thank you so much. what changes have you made in the code? I want to ignore imaginary part because it is physically impossible so I think it will be very small and negligible.

Comment: Just `mg*yg''[t] == NN[t] - kb*Re[yg[t]^1.0001] - cb*yg'[t]`.  Nothing else.